# MS Access Form won't update after passing value to combobox

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access, combobox

Open new form via button on another form and pass a value to a combobox in the new form to select a specific data set. After passing of the value to the combobox, the form won't update.

I use a form *form1* in MS Access with a button *myButton*, which again opens a new form *form2*. There are two comboboxes on form2 to select a specific data set. After opening form2, I want *comboBox1* to be set to a value depending on the current dataset in form1. The second combobox *comboBox2* holds a list of values generated in a query, which again depends on the value in comboBox1: The two values from comboBox1 and comboBox2 are related 1:n, so after the value in comboBox1 is selected, the (embedded) query in comboBox2 returns all data sets available for value1 in comboBox1. From the list of this query, I want comboBox2 to be initialised with the first available value.

I found the following code to set the values in both comboboxes:

```vb
Private Sub cmdMyButton_Click()

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmForm2"
    Forms!frmForm2.comboBox1 = Me.Value1
    Forms!frmForm2.comboBox2 = Forms!frmForm2.comboBox2.ItemData(0)
    
End Sub
```

Up to that point, everything works fine and as expected. However, the data set shown in form2 will always be the first data set of the underlying table, although the values in both comboboxes would require another data set to be selected. As soon as I change the value in combobox2, the form is updated correctly.

I tried different update methods, like `Requiry`, `Recalc`, `Refresh` and `After_Update`, but the form won't be updated (or an error is thrown).

Answer (score 0):

Once the value of `comboBox1` has been set, you need to requery `comboBox2` to update its list, since it's dependent on the value of the 1st combobox.

Also, I'm pretty sure this line is incorrect since it references the same control (unless it's a typo).

Try this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmForm2"

With Forms.frmForm2
    .comboBox1 = Me.Value1
    .comboBox2.Requery
    .comboBox2 = .comboBox1.ItemData(0)
    .Requery
End With
```

Comment: Hi Kostas, thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately, it didn't work. The line you are referencing to is no typo: The available list of options in comboBox2 is generated by a query (embedded in the combo box) - this query is dependet on comboBox1 (the boxes are cascaded). I want to initialise comboBox2 with the first element of the list gained from this query. And this works well, except, that the rest of the form won't get updated, as soon as this first element is selected.
I tried to `Requery` as you stated, but unfortunately the result is the same.

Comment: I edited the question to clearify the cascading of comboBox1 and comboBox2.